# LINQ search list of type Node with WHERE

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of points which i have set like this:

```
List<Node> points = new List<Node>();
```

I just started to use LINQ to find a particular item in the list based on my search parameters like so:

```
Node T = points.Where(v => v.x == position[0] && v.y == position[1]);
```

How ever this gives the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Node>' to `Node'
```

So i guess i misunderstood how it works, i presumed it would return the Node in the list that it found or simply null.

What data type is it suppose to be when using `Where` on a list, am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension method `Where`
Will return multiple items: `IEnumerable<Node>`
If you expect one item based on your filter, you can use:

```
Node T = points.FirstOrDefault(v => v.x == position[0] && v.y == position[1]);
```

If no Node is found for your filter, `default(Node)` will be returned (that is: `null` if Node is a class)
There are other extension methods you could use, like:

```
First(), Single(), SingleOrDefault()
```

[This link](http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/) will give you details on their characteristics.

Comment: So if it finds more than one what is the best way to handle it ?

Comment: If you only want the first one (regardless of how many returned), and you don't want to throw if None is found. Use FirstOrDefault(). If you use only First(), it will throw an exception is none is found. Personally I always use FirstOrDefault then I check myself if I found an item (e.g: if (node == null) so I can throw a more friendly exception (One node excepted for Y and X values)

Answer (score 2):

`Where` returns `IEnumerable<Node>` not `Node`. This is because there could be more than one result.

If you want to return only a single item, use `Single`, `First`, or `Last` instead. If there may be no matching items, use `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`, or `LastOrDefault`.

So, `Where` returns all matching results, `Single` returns the only matching result or throws an exception if there are zero or multiple results, and `SingleOrDefault` return the only matching result, the default value (`null`, 0, "", etc.) if there are zero results, or throws an exception if there are multiple results.

`First` and `FirstOrDefault` are similar to `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` except that they will not throw an exception if there are multiple results, rather they will return the first matching value. `Last` and `LastOrDefault` works exactly the same, except for the last matching value.

So, assuming you know there is only one matching `Node`, you would do this:

```
Node T = points.Single(v => v.x == position[0] && v.y == position[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.Where` returns all points matching your condition.
Instead you need only one point.
Use `FirstOrDefault` for retrieve only one result.

Try this:

```
Node T = points.Where(v => v.x == position[0] && v.y == position[1]).FirstOrDefault();`
```

Comment: There's no reason to call `Where` followed by `FirstOrDefault`. You can use `FirstOrDefault` directly.

Comment: Bruno, if you need to teach anything you must make it simple.